# Running jQuery in Project Details Page

Tags: jquery, ms-project-server-2010

I am trying to limit the length of the "Project Notes" Custom Field in Project Details Page (PDP) using Project Server 2010.
I am using the following jQuery in a Content Editor Web Part added to the PDP:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var textArea = $("textarea[title$='Project Notes']");
        textArea.keypress(function() 
        { 
            var text = textArea.text();
            if(text.length > 10) 
            { 
                alert("Project Notes cannot exceed 100 characters in length."); 
                textArea.val(text.substring(0,9)); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

However, when the user types into the text area nothing is happening.The event does not fire. I have tried various modifications to the code but the same result.
Please let me know what I am missing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxlength` attribute for html element.

```
<textarea maxlength="10" rows='5' cols='25'></textarea>
```

and if we go with your script then use `.val()` instead of `.text()`. form elements does have values where you have to input the text. whether that is `input type text` or `textarea`.

```
var textArea = $("textarea[title$='Project Notes']");
textArea.keypress(function () {
   var text = textArea.val();
   if (text.length > 10) {
      alert("Project Notes cannot exceed 100 characters in length.");
      textArea.val(text.substring(0, 9));
   }
});
```

You can try this out in [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WuctG/)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, however, the suggested solution does not work. The problem is that the event is not firing inside the Project Server page. Even if I remove the the code inside the keypress function and keep a simple alert, it still does not execute as well. I tried using keyup instead of keypress but same result. Events are not firing when the user types into the text area.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the text area to a text box and the events started firing normally.